# How to create a like lock in blogger or other html site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, blogger

I would like to know what code I could create a page that can be visible only after clicking on the facebook "like" button.
I know the plug-in for WordPress "wp-like lock", but if I wanted to create a html template for blogger or other platform?

Comment: That's a pretty evil thing to do.

Comment: Why is wrong with WP LIKE LOCK?

Answer (score 0):

Evil, but this might be what you're looking for:
http://likelock.me/

Not sure if they have an API for automatically generating locked links...